# Printing SD Card File contents on LCD

Tags: atmega, c, sd, character-lcd

This is a part of my program which reads data from SD card File and Display that on LCD screen.

```
  File dataFile = SD.open("1165.txt");


  if (dataFile) {
    Serial.println("File Opened");
    lcd.clear();
    delay( 5 );  //LCD-specific M
    lcd.setCursor( 0,0 );
    while (dataFile.available()) {
      Serial.write(dataFile.read());
      lcd.write(dataFile.read());
      lcd.print(dataFile.read());
     }
     dataFile.close();
     } else {
        // if the file didn't open, print an error:
        Serial.println("error");
     }
```

When I look at the Serial Monitor It prints the contents of that File but

nun of these commands prints what is printed in the serial monitor,

```
lcd.write(dataFile.read());
lcd.print(dataFile.read());
```

Any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared the file handle as "datafile", but your functions refer to "dataafile" (with two "a"s) Perhaps a typo?

I expect the line "Serial.write(dataaFile.read());" will read the file, and advance the file pointer to the end of the file.  The two lcd.write() calls will attempt to read beyond the end of the file.

You probably need to read the file into a buffer, then write the contents of the buffer to the serial port and to the LCD.

Comment: Originally I have used dataaFile but when I post in the question. I have changed that to dataFile,  here I missed correcting that, but in the real code it is correct

Comment: any other idea?

Comment: As far as I can judge the code @PeterBennett is correct and has already posted the correct answer. I **think** that read will only read a single char. Your Serial.write will read the first char, then lcd.write will read the second, lcd.print will read the third; the loop will start then again from the fourth char. As Peter Bennett stated, read the char into a variable, then use the content of that variable to print the character three times. This will make sure that no further characters are read.

Comment: Example code (probably formats really badly):
while (dataFile.available()) {
  char c = dataFile.read();
  Serial.write(c);
  lcd.write(c);
  lcd.print(c);
}

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (dataFile) {
    char character;
    Serial.println("File Opened");
    lcd.clear();
    delay( 5 );  //LCD-specific M
    lcd.setCursor( 0,0 );
    while (dataFile.available()) {
      character = dataFile.read();
      Serial.write(character);
      lcd.write(character);
      lcd.print(character);
     }
     dataFile.close();
     } else {
        // if the file didn't open, print an error:
        Serial.println("error");
     }
```

Comment: Would you care to ellaborate on how this solves the OP problem? Took me a while to see the difference from the original code as well. You should point out what you changed in the original code.